# Concatenating column values in shared row value with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to merge many different arrays that share a common column, based on this column's values (Time).
So far I can concatenate the arrays but can't figure out how to merge them properly so that I get this **desired output**:

```
   Time  Temperature  Height  Width
      0         50.0    10.0    3.0
      5         50.0    11.0    3.0
     10        100.0    13.0    3.0
     15        100.0    15.0    3.0
     20        120.0    15.0    5.0
     25        100.0    15.0    5.0
     40        100.0    15.0    6.0
```

This is the sample code:

```py
array=pd.DataFrame({'Time': [0,10,20,25],'Temperature': [50,100,120,100]})
array2=pd.DataFrame({'Time': [0,5,10,15],'Height': [10,11,13,15]})
array3=pd.DataFrame({'Time': [0,20,40],'Width': [3,5,6]})
concat_df_a = pd.concat([array,array2,array3])
concat_df_a.sort_values(by='Time', ascending=True, inplace=True)
    concat_df_a
```

with output as:

```
   Time  Temperature  Height  Width
0     0         50.0     NaN    NaN
0     0          NaN    10.0    NaN
0     0          NaN     NaN    3.0
1     5          NaN    11.0    NaN
1    10        100.0     NaN    NaN
2    10          NaN    13.0    NaN
3    15          NaN    15.0    NaN
2    20        120.0     NaN    NaN
1    20          NaN     NaN    5.0
3    25        100.0     NaN    NaN
2    40          NaN     NaN    6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate `sum` with `min_count=1` for misisng values and forward filling them by `ffill`:

```
concat_df_a = pd.concat([array,array2,array3]).groupby('Time').sum(min_count=1).ffill()
print(concat_df_a)
       Temperature  Height  Width
Time                            
0            50.0    10.0    3.0
5            50.0    11.0    3.0
10          100.0    13.0    3.0
15          100.0    15.0    3.0
20          120.0    15.0    5.0
25          100.0    15.0    5.0
40          100.0    15.0    6.0
```